# Is it a bad practice by assigning vector::size() to a auto const reference?

Tags: c++, vector, size

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(12);
    const auto& cnt = vec.size();
    cout<<cnt<<endl;
}
```

My mentor says `const auto&` is a bad style, could you tell me why?

Comment: `const auto&` on trivial types can often be a form of premature optimization, where it actually takes a bit more effort to make a reference alias than it would to copy the underlying trivial type. Especially `const auto&` where the right hand side of the assignment is an rvalue that's going away anyway--what's it a reference _to_? Nothing, it's functionally just `auto cnt = vec.size();` but obfuscated.

Comment: There are cases in which binding a temporary to a reference is safe. I avoid them for I am not able to remember them.